# Start Skype voice call from addressbook in ICS

Tags: contacts, skype

I have ICS and Skype 4.4. Some of the contacts in my Android addressbook have a "Chat" contact of type "Skype".
When I have Skype open, is there a way to start a voice call to this Skype contact directly from the addressbook, i.e. without switching to the Skype app?

**EDIT:** By voice call I mean a call via the Skype network, i.e. to the Skype contact, *not* a Skype call to the contact's phone number.

Comment: Have you tried to simply initiate a call? Unless you've set another app as default, there should be a popup to let you chose the app to continue with: Dialer, Skype, and whatever else you've installed. As long as those apps have registered for this, that is – but I cannot imagine Skype didn't do that, so it should work.